# How many positive values of $a$ are possible in $2^{3}\le a\lfloor a\rfloor \le 4^{2} + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many positive values of $a$ are possible in the following case?
$$2^{3}\le a\lfloor a\rfloor \le 4^{2} + 1$$
where $a\lfloor a\rfloor$ such that $a[a]$ is an integer.

Comment: Why is $a[a]$ necessarily an integer? e.g. $2.3[2.3] = 4.6$

Comment: Its a condition given in the original question.

Comment: Then it that case it may be better phrased as "such that $a[a]$ is an integer" (otherwise there is an ambiguity that $a[a]$ is always an integer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clear that $\lfloor a\rfloor$ must be $\ge 3$ and $\le 4$.

In the case $\lfloor a\rfloor=3$, the product can be $9$, $10$, or $11$.  For $8$ is too small, since $a\ge \lfloor a\rfloor$. And $12$ is too big, since then $a=4$, giving the wrong value for the floor function. So $a$ can have values $3$, $10/3$, and $11/3$.

In the case $\lfloor a\rfloor=4$ there are two possible values of the product, $16$ and $17$.

So the number of possible values of $a$ is $5$.

Answer (score 0):

$[a] ≤ a  => [a][a] ≤ a[a]≤17  =>[a]≤4$

and

$a ≥ [a]  => a.a ≥a[a] ≥ 8 =>a≥\sqrt8$

$=>3≤[a]≤4$

If $ [a]=3,  3≤a<4 =>3.3≤a[a]<4.3 => 9≤a[a]<12$ which satisfies the given condition.

So, $9≤3a<12=>\frac{9}{3}≤a<\frac{12}{3}=>a=\frac{9}{3}, \frac{10}{3},  \frac{11}{3}$

If $[a]=4, 4≤a<5 =>16≤a[a]<20$,

but according to the given condition $8≤a[a]≤17$

So, here $16≤a[a]≤17=>16≤4a≤17=>a=\frac{16}{4}, \frac{17}{4}$

Comment: There *must* be a better way to format this...